# Try and catch method not working java

Tags: java

I have been trying to get my try/catch set up to work but it doesn't seem to run either the try section or the catch section and just returns the default value of the variable.

I had it working before and cant remember what it was that i changed because I haven't touched it for a while

i can include the data file if requested

Any ideas?

```
package firsttry;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class csv{
    public double speed(int tool , int block){
    double blockbreak = 0;
    //Define file variable thing

    //runs through file 
    try {
        String filename = "data.csv";
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
        //runs through each line as long as there is something next
        while (inputStream.hasNext()){
            String data = inputStream.next();//gets a whole line
            String[] values = data.split(",");
            if (values[1].equals(block)){
                blockbreak = Double.parseDouble(values[tool + 2]);
                System.out.println(blockbreak);
                blockbreak = 4;
            }
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
        blockbreak = 4;
    }
    return blockbreak;


}

public String name(int block){
    String filename = "data.csv";
    File file = new File(filename);

    //runs through file 
    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
        //runs through each line as long as there is something next
        while (inputStream.hasNext()){
            String data = inputStream.next();//gets a whole line
            String[] values = data.split(",");
            if (values[1].equals(block)){
                //int speed = Integer.parseInt(values[tool]);
                String blockname = values[0];
                return blockname;
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return filename;
}


}
```

Comment: which method? which default value is it returning? Imagine you didn't know the code, would the question be easy to answer? Have you stepped though the code using a debugger? What does it do?

Comment: Also the code is very improperly indented, so I'm less inclined to take you seriously since you haven't taken the simplest steps to solve the problem on your own.  Edit your question to Include the exact error you receive below the code.

Comment: Is there data in `data.csv`?

Comment: This calls for breakpoints.  You can see what the value is and how many times it loops etc.  Perhaps your conditions are not working...

Comment: Yes there is data in there about 25 lines

Comment: Anyone offer any solutions? I have fixed all the problems that you have highlighted in the question

Comment: We could try contacting James Gosling and informing him that his try/catch is broken, as you say in the title.  Use e.printStackTrace() in your catch block, and then include the error message you get below your code.

Comment: I see that you have an Sysout statement inside the if case, that is the only place where the value of `blockbreak` is changed. Is that sysout statement printed?

If not, use the Eclipse or IntelliJ debugger and go through the code line by line, check the values of variables at each step and may be you will see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have enough reputation to comment, so writing here.

You should modify your if condition in each function() written above,

```
if (values[1].equals(block)){
}
```

It will not give you an output you are expecting.

Comparing string with int is incorrect, for example

```
 System.out.println("1".equals(1));  -> will print false
```

Answer (score 0):

You are observing that the default value is being returned.

Does this mean that your function returns 0? (As initialized here? `double blockbreak = 0;`)

If that is the case, you should look into what happens in your loop.

This if statement looks dodgy.

`if (values[1].equals(block))`

What do you expect to happen?

Also, please post a line that matches the if statement and a line that doesn't, and the expected output from the function.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons why you only get the default value:

1. `data.csv` is an empty file.
2. `values[1].equals(block)` returns false. (Which will always be the case since you're comparing a `String` to an `int`.)
3. `catch (FileNotFoundException e)` doesn't do anything, so you wouldn't know if the file was not found.

To elaborate on point 2, consider `values[1].equals(String.valueOf(block))`

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest some troubleshooting tips.

Write a unit test so you can easily run this repeatedly.

Put a System.out.println into the code in a few places to see which places it hits and when (On small problems this is often easier than debugging if you don't typically debug, I often have it print out a letter at the beginning of any code that comes after a decision point like if, loop and try/catch constructs.)

Print out the value of each line as you read it.

Print the value of blockbreak

I would guess your loop or the if statement aren't executing.  Printing some values will tell you this quickly.

Also, if you truly intend Blockbreak to be assigned a value, try NOT assigning a default value of 0 in the beginning.  This will stop you from compiling until you have assigned a value in every possible program flow path--a very handy feature (May not help in your case because of the way your while loop is structured, but it's a useful habit not to assign initial values until you need to in Java).